# php preg_match - search for specific number/character code

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I'm trying to search for a number/character pattern inside of a string.

The String can look like this

```
"any text CA-2019-6-000000 any text" 
"any text KA 2019-2-929029" // note: no "-" between the "KA and 2019" 
"KA-2019-11-929029"
```

What I can definetly say, There is always a year, like `2000/2019/2055`.
After the year is always a minus sign, two possible numbers from 1-12 and another minus sign.

Which is the month.

And after the "`-<num>-`", is a 6 digits long number which can be at least `000000` or max `999999`

Before the year, can be max. two characters long string followed by a minus.
Between this two characters long strong could be a minus sign or a space letter.

Examples:

```
"AA 2019"
"ZZ-2018"
```

I found out that I could get the 6 numbers with `/[0-9]{6}/`.

The year by `/[0-9]{4}`. I would like to add, that it only can be between `2000 and 2100`

And I can get the number between the two minus signs with: `/(?<=\-)(.*?)(?=\-)/` or

`/\-(.*?)\-/`

---

For example, I had the idea to look for the number between the two "-" characters and store it in a variable.
Then to say I want to have the numbers between the ones after this variable that are 6 characters long and between 000000 and 999999.

A similar game with that year. I'd want to say I'd get the number which is before the variable with the "--" The maximum length is 4 numbers and is between 2000 and 2100.

If I then have stored the year in a variable I can theoretically say I'm looking for two letters which precede "-$yearvariable" or " [space]$yearvariable

Comment: Please give a proper example of what you actually want as result here, based on that shown input data.

Comment: Oh as a result I want to have the thos example options at the top of the questions. Like KA-2019-11-929029 or CA 2019-6-000000 .

Comment: Like the text which could possible be after and before this code, should be removed and I want the code which starts with the two characters and ends with the 6 letters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
\b([A-Z]{2})[-\s](20[0-9]{2}|2100)-(0?[1-9]|1[0-2])-(\d{6})(?!\d)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/vtmrtZ/1)

**Details**

- `\b` - word boundary
- `([A-Z]{2})` - two uppercase letters
- `[-\s]` - a hyphen or whitespace
- `(20[0-9]{2}|2100)` - number from 2000 to 2100
- `-` -  a hyphen
- `(0?[1-9]|1[0-2])` -  a month from 1 to 12
- `-`  -  a hyphen
- `(\d{6})(?!\d)` - 6 digits (no 7 or more).

See the [regex graph](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%5Cb(%5BA-Z%5D%7B2%7D)%5B-%5Cs%5D(20%5B0-9%5D%7B2%7D%7C2100)-(0%3F%5B1-9%5D%7C1%5B0-2%5D)-(%5Cd%7B6%7D)(%3F!%5Cd)):

[image]

[image]

[PHP demo](https://3v4l.org/XOINv):

```
$s = "any text CA-2019-6-000000 any text";
if (preg_match('~\b([A-Z]{2})[-\s](20[0-9]{2}|2100)-(0?[1-9]|1[0-2])-(\d{6})(?!\d)~', $s, $m)) { 
    print_r($m);
}
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => CA-2019-6-000000
    [1] => CA
    [2] => 2019
    [3] => 6
    [4] => 000000
)
```

Comment: @blyadjs I thought you also needed all those parts of the regex match, so I used capturing groups (`(...)`). If you do not need them, turn all the capturing groups into non-capturing by replacing `(...)` with `(?:...)`. Also, use [this generator](http://gamon.webfactional.com/regexnumericrangegenerator/) for numeric ranges, it looks helpful (though sometimes, the patterns are a bit redundant).